# "Free heap block modified after it was freed" when modifying string after malloc

Tags: gdb, malloc, memcpy, c89, string.h

I am currently working on a project that includes some file I/O.

Due to it being cross platform I needed to account for different path separators and hence decided to create the following function to simplify the process of joining paths:

```
/**
 * @brief Joins two paths together.
 * 
 * path = a + seperator + b + '\0'
 * 
 * @param a First path.
 * @param b Second path.
 * 
 * @return A pointer to the two paths combined.
 */
char * join_paths(const char * a, const char * b)
{
    const char separator[] =
    #ifdef _WIN32
        "\\";
    #else
        "/";
    #endif


    /* Get the sizes of all the strings
       to join.                         */
    size_t a_len = strlen(a);
    size_t b_len = strlen(b);
    size_t s_len = strlen(separator);
    size_t total_len = a_len + b_len + s_len + 1; /* +1 for \0 */

    /* path will contain a, b, the separator and \0
       hence the total length is total_len.
    */
    char * path = malloc(total_len);
    check( path != NULL,
           "Error allocating memory for path. " );

    memcpy(path, a, a_len);          /* path will begin with a */

    strncat(path, separator, s_len); /* copy separator */
    strncat(path, b, b_len);         /* copy b         */

error:

    return path;
}
```

(Where `check` is a macro from here: http://pastebin.com/2mZxSX3S)

Which had been working fine until now, when I had to use GDB to debug something not related to file I/O and realized that all my file paths seemed to be corrupt (e.g. "¡║¯½½½½½½½½■¯■¯■¯■").

Also I got the error message:

> "Free heap block modified after it was freed"

After further investigation I realized this all happens after the `memcpy` in `join_paths`.

However this all seems to only happen when running it from GDB. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `memcpy` did not zero-terminate the target buffer. Meanwhile, `strncat` requires a valid string as the target. Without proper zero-termination your `strncat` calls began concatenation at some unpredictable spot further down the buffer, eventually running over the end of the buffer.

Quite possibly you can fix it by just doing

```
memcpy(path, a, a_len + 1);
```

to ensure the terminating zero is also copied.

But why are you mixing `mem...` functions and `str...` functions? It is possible to do it properly, but you have to be constantly paying attention to such things as proper zero-termination before you use any `str...` function.

One can argue that when the length of the string is already known, `mem...` functions are more appropriate and efficient than `str..` functions. In that case, just stick to `mem...` functions. For example, in your case this should work properly

```
memcpy(path, a, a_len);
memcpy(path + a_len, separator, s_len);
memcpy(path + a_len + s_len, b, b_len + 1);
```

Alternatively (and maybe even better), you can use `sprintf` (or `snprintf`) to do it in one line

```
size_t n_written = sprintf(path, "%s%s%s", a, separator, b);
assert(n_written + 1 == total_len);
```

Comment: I know this is late but I would just like to add in case of any future viewers that `snprintf` is `c99` and `sprintf` is specified in `c90`. Due to portability I was required to use `c89` and hence did not use them originally.My fault for leaving it out the question, sorry.